# git clean master branch in repository

Tags: git

Hello I have setup two branches in my repository master and dev.

By mistake, I had uploaded my code to master instead of dev.

So, How to clear the master branch using local repository?

Comment: Merge it into dev, and remove everything from it..

Comment: Can you push the changes to dev and revert the master?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue from locally created git.
The steps I followed are:

git clone https://your_repo_url/

git status   #check if you are in master branch.

git branch clean_up

git checkout clean_up

git rm *.*   #remove all files from current folder.

git rm -r *  #remove all folder and their data.

git checkout master

git merge clean_up

git branch -d clean_up

git push

That's it.

Done.

Comment: It seems that this procedure doesn't delete the history.

Answer (score 1):

you need to reset your code first with below command.

> git reset --hard HEAD~1

and then use below command to push your code to dev branch

> git push -f origin dev

Comment: Don't forget a forced push will overwrite history on remote which might result in huge trouble with other contributers.

Answer (score 0):

go to the folder you have pushed your code to master branch and use the following command

git reset --hard HEAD~1

create a new folder clone your code to that folder

git checkout dev

put your code to this folder

git commit -a -m "first code to dev"

git push origin dev